# Expected value of steps needed to exceed the sum

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

> Suppose you have numbers $\{x_{1}=40,\ldots,x_{21} = 60\}$. Next, on each step you are given one of these numbers randomly (the probability of getting the particular number is the same for all of them). What is the expected value of steps before sum of numbers exceeds $10\;000$?

I've solved this problem by just considering $\mathbb{E}(s) = 1 + \dfrac{1}{21}\left[\mathbb{E}(s+40)+\ldots+\mathbb{E}(s+60)\right]$, starting with $s=10\;000$ and going down, so that the pattern becomes obvious. But I wonder if there is a more beautiful approach? Because this one is still a bit tedious.

Comment: There is an elegant way to write it in terms of the probability that, after $N$ steps, the total is at least $M$. Not sure that has an elegant form though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a beautiful way to get an approximate answer.

Let $N$ be the number of steps it takes to first exceed $10,000$. On the one hand, the expected total after $N$ steps is
$$
\mathbb E[N]\cdot 50,
$$
since each step contributes $50$ on average. On the other hand, after $N$ steps, you know the total will be between $10,001$ and $10,060$. Therefore,
$$
10,001\le \mathbb E[N]\cdot 50\le 10,060,
$$
which implies
$$
200.02\le \mathbb E[N]\le 201.2
$$
So $E[N]$ is just a little more than $200$.